# Setting permanent path through a script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to add a folder to the PATH in linux. I want to automate it through a script.
This is the script I have written:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Setting PATH..."
echo "export PATH=$PATH:/opt/mysoftware/scripts/client" >> ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc
```

Even after executing the script, PATH is not getting updated.
But I can see that bashrc file has been updated.

When I logout and login, PATH is updated.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running the script in a child shell. Try sourcing it:

```
source script.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want this in your .bashrc, delete the script. You're done now. ;-)

The alternative is to put this in a function.  I used to have two functions,
`use()` and `forget()` in my ksh environment that did exactly that.

`use /opt/python` would be equivalent to `PATH=/opt/python/bin:$PATH`, once.
A second run would do nothing.  Even `use python` would look in a couple of
locations for /{usr,opt}/python/{bin,sbin} and insert the first match to PATH.

Conversely,  `forget python` would remove `/opt/python/bin:` from the PATH again.